# "Avere la stiva carica" è un'espressione idiomatica?

Tags: idioms, regional

Nel romanzo ***Il corso delle cose*** di Andrea Camilleri ho letto:

> "Per scrupolo, camminò ancora fino alla piazzetta dove Corbo gli aveva
>   spiegato che quello abitava, ma non notò niente che meritasse, c'erano
>   solo due persone che parlavano nella parte più scura della piazza,
>   dalla voce impastata si capiva che *avevano la stiva carica*."

Capisco che in questa frase "avere la stiva carica" significa "essere ubriaco" per analogia a una nave carica di merci. Comunque mi domando se "avere la stiva carica" con questo significato sia un'espressione idiomatica della lingua italiana.

Comment: A Roma, non pervenuto. Se è un'espressione idiomatica, sarà siciliana. D'altronde la lingua di Camilleri è anche molto ricca di invenzioni.

Comment: @DaG: Può darsi che sia un'invenzione di Camilleri.

Comment: [Mi sembra di capire](http://www.academia.edu/7868028/Alle_radici_dellidioletto_camilleriano._Sulle_varianti_dei_Corso_delle_cose_1978_e_1998_) che è il siciliano di Camilleri.

Comment: Vedi Appendice A, pagina 263, in _Regionalismi fraseologici_: «avevano la stiva carica 88 / ubriaco che non reggeva il carico 103». Quindi il significato è "erano ubriachi da non reggersi in piedi".

Comment: @randomatlabuser: Questo testo dell'Appendice significa che, nella pagina 88 del romanzo, appare l'espressione «avevano la stiva carica» e, nella pagina 103, c'è scritto «un ubriaco che non reggeva il carico». Dunque, sembra che si tratti di un'espressione idiomatica siciliana.

Comment: È principalmente la pagina 88 dell'edizione del 1978 edita da Lalli (Camilleri A. 1978, Il corso delle cose, Lalli, Poggibonsi); sembra che poi il concetto venga ribadito alla pagina 103 della stessa edizione. Il saggio è molto interessante perché studia le varie rimaneggiature del romanzo, specialmente riguardo al mistilinguismo di Camilleri che dovette fare i conti con un mercato del libro che non era pronto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Un [saggio di Gigliola Sulis](http://www.academia.edu/7868028/Alle_radici_dellidioletto_camilleriano._Sulle_varianti_dei_Corso_delle_cose_1978_e_1998_) (Alle radici dell'idioletto camilleriano. Sulle varianti de *Il corso delle cose* (1978, 1998)) affronta la questione del mistilinguismo di Andrea Camilleri nella prima opera di narrativa estesa dell'autore siciliano, ripercorrendo anche le vicende editoriali, i notevoli rimaneggiamenti resi necessari da un mercato editoriale che forse non era pronto, o forse gli editori non ritenevano pronto, ad un esperimento del genere.

Nel saggio l'espressione viene inserita, insieme a molte altre, nell'Appendice A, pagina 263, in *Regionalismi fraseologici* («avevano la stiva carica 88 / ubriaco che non reggeva il carico 103»). Si tratta quindi di fraseologia regionale - siciliana - che viene parzialmente italianizzata con lo scopo di:

- rendere il racconto realistico, utilizzando la lingua e l'immaginario dei personaggi
- sperimentare un innovativo stile narrativo/espositivo
- sdoganare il dialetto siciliano, portarlo fuori dagli angusti confini isolani
- rendere l'espressione la più comprensibile possibile ad un pubblico non siciliano.

Quindi, in conclusione, forse non si tratta di un'espressione idiomatica della lingua italiana, e neanche di un'espressione puramente dialettale - più che altro il frutto di un esperimento di contaminazione linguistica, un'espressione forse idiomatica del dialetto siciliano (o forse del tutto inventata dallo scrittore) che viene resa/proposta in italiano.

Credo che alla fine l'esperimento debba considerarsi riuscito, se è vero che il significato si riesce a ricavare dal contesto. Rimane comunque incerto che poi l'espressione si diffonda.

Answer (score -1):

No, 'avere la stiva carica' non è italiano idiomatico, ma, in generale, non è raro che scrittori italici introducano, italianizzandole, forme dialettali nei loro romanzi con la speranza che possano diventare idiomi.
I fallimenti al riguardo sono innumerevoli.

Comment: Non credo che questa sia l'intenzione dell'autore. Secondo me, Camilleri cerca di descrivere quello che un personaggio sta pensando in quel momento e lo fa usando le parole che passano per la testa di tale personaggio. Essendo questo personaggio siciliano, è naturale che si esprima così.

Comment: Penso che Camilleri sia un grande maestro di questo artificio letterario: è capace di introdurre forme dialettali e regionalismi provenenti anche di altre regioni d'Italia quando ci sono personaggi originari di tali regioni.

Comment: @Elberich, hai notato che le prime parole della tua risposta ripetono senza fonti qualcosa che è già stato detto, in modo supportato da un utile riferimento bibliografico, da randomatlabuser, e che il resto è composto da tue discutibili opinioni non pertinenti alla domanda?

Comment: Sì, in effetti c'è un po' di criticismo letterario nella risposta, vedrò di rimediare.